# HTML code for attaching a google group to my website

Tags: html, web

I want to attach a google group to my website. Is there a way to do that? please help. I need HTML code to attach this group to my website.

Comment: [Stack Overflow is not your personal research assistant](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128553/140505)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an iframe and some JavaScript

```
<iframe id="forum_embed"
 src="javascript:void(0)"
 scrolling="no"
 frameborder="0"
 width="900"
 height="700">
</iframe>

<script type="text/javascript">
 document.getElementById("forum_embed").src =
  "https://groups.google.com/forum/embed/?place=forum/forum-name" +
  "&showsearch=true&showpopout=true&parenturl=" +
  encodeURIComponent(window.location.href);
</script>
```

where forum-name is the name of your Google group

Read more about it [here](http://support.google.com/groups/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1191206)

See this [jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/jackdent/yV9Vm/) for the group foresite